# Syntax for Git Submodule Foreach Pull?

Tags: git

I've cloned a repository that has submodules in it and the submodules have all been git-inited and git-updated.  After a changed has been pushed into one or more submodules (by another machine) I run this command:

```
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

to get the latest locally - but when I enter into my submodules and do a `git status` I get a "Not currently on any branch" message.  I then have to do a combination of `git checkout` and `git pull` to get back on track to the submodule's master branch.

If my goal is to do a "get latest from the main branch" across all of my submodules, what is the correct foreach command?

**Edit for Example**:

Consider this:

1. I have a repository A with a submodule B and two machines, Z and Y
2. I clone the repository and submodule onto Y and Z.
3. I make a change in B on Y and push it back to the server.

Now, what I'm asking for is the syntax to bring Z up to date and get the latest change in B - in such a way that it can scale for multiple submodules.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to get all changes on all submodules and merge them in. If so `git submodule update --merge` should do the trick. Not sure why you even tried to use foreach there.

Comment: I've tried that but I'm still stuck with the "Not currently on any branch" message within my submodule.  I want my submodule to be on its respective the master branch.

Comment: Huh as stated in the documentation thats excactly whats not supposed to happen.